# Problems with stored procedure in DB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which picks up data of specific order (all the products which have been bought with that order) and I have implemented a grading system where each buyer can rate the products he bought. Now my problem is, when 1 buyer rates all the products he bought (lets say 3 products), and now when the next buyer comes, buys all 3 same products , and when he gets in the form for rating the products, he gets the grades of the previous guy who rated those (lets say 4,5 and 1 grade).  Here is the stored procedure I use:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[hsp_Narudzbe_Detalji2]
(
@NarudzbaID int
)
as
select ns.*,p.Naziv,p.Sifra,p.Cijena,ISNULL(o.Ocjena,-1) as Ocjena
from NarudzbeStavke as ns join Proizvodi as p 
on ns.ProizvodID= p.ProizvodID left join ocjene as o 
on o.ProizvodID=p.ProizvodID 
where ns.NarudzbaID = @NarudzbaID
```

As you can see, I select all the products which have been ordered for a specific order ( where ns.narudzbaid=@NarudzbaID) and I also do left join to see which products haven't been rated yet. Now I'd like to kick out the ratings of the 1st buyer so that the 2nd buyer can insert his grades also?
Can someone help me up with this?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You tagged mysql and sql-server. They are not the same thing. Some ddl and sample data would go a long way to getting you some help. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Comment: im using mssql,  i made a mistake with tags. i just wanna know if this is doable? im sure it can be done via sub queries but im just not that good with sql :(

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are trying to do but it seems that is shouldn't be a huge deal.

Comment: Lets say one user rates one product via grid(the grade is selected from drop list) and when he grades it, the drop list is gone and just the grade is there. Now 2nd user buys same product and when he tries to rate it, hes not able to see the drop list for rating, but instead the grade from the user that first graded the product. I would like to eliminate the grade from first user for the 2nd user so that he can insert his own grade. Is it any more clear now?

Comment: As I said before...post some ddl and sample data. Got to sqlfiddle.com to get started.

Comment: Do you need the db schema ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65240/discussion-between-perkes456-and-sean-lange).

Comment: Yes and some data. I can't possibly put together a query without tables and some data to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to store orderid and buyerid in ocjene table and have to join it as following:

left join

ocjene as o

on

o.ProizvodID = p.ProizvodID AND

o.buyerid = ns.[field of buyer/customer id] AND

o.NarudzbaID = ns.NarudzbaID

Comment: oh? Wait i'll try that method

Comment: @perkes456 without buyer id you can not identify which customer has given which score to product.